# Wordpress Errors Upon Install Caused By Permissions

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions

Working on the following site and I'm getting errors caused by permissions (http://tinyurl.com/loal49y). I have tried to edit the settings on the wp-settings.php file from 644 to 755 and then to 777, however none of them worked. I'm out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to CHMOD all the files/folders in `/wp-content/` to `0755` (not just wp-settings.php which happens to be triggering the error).

If that doesn't do the trick, you'll need to change ownership (CHOWN) `/wp-content/` and all subfiles/folders to the user and group of your web server software (sometimes it's apache:apache, but will depend on your environment).

Comment: Just did that and still no dice.

Comment: Check out the owner/group and see if they need to be updated with `CHOWN` from Linux terminal. That's often the problem.

Comment: Forgot to select recurse into files as well as directories. Worked perfectly. Thanks!